# Delphi 11 Alexandria Ribbons Classic Controls support

Tags: delphi, ribbon-control, delphi-11-alexandria

With Delphi 10 Seattle the Ribbons Classic Controls were included in the regular shipment.

Starting with Delphi 10.4 Sydney the Ribbons Classic Controls have to be installed via GetIt-Package-Manager. So far so good.

Now, with Delphi 11 Alexandria I installed the Ribbon Classic Controls via GetIt-Package-Manager. I can't compile some of my projects because it's missing a few class implementations like TScreenTipsPopup, TScreenTipItem for example.

```
[dcc32 Fehler] Vcl.Ribbon.pas(763): E2003 Undeklarierter Bezeichner: 'TScreenTipsPopup'
[dcc32 Fehler] Vcl.Ribbon.pas(771): E2003 Undeklarierter Bezeichner: 'TScreenTipItem'
```

[image: Seattle Ribbon]
[image: Seattle ScreenTips]

Delphi 10 Seattle provided those implementations in the unit Vcl.ScreenTips.pas.

[image: Seattle cmd]

As you can see here, it does not exists any unit with "TScreenTipsPopup = class".

[image: Alexandria cmd]

But I have the Vcl.Ribbon.pas unit. So that it can't be said that I simply copied the unit. I have installed the GetIt-Package:

[image: Alexandria GetIt]

**Now my real question:**

What am I doing wrong? How can I fix this? Help?!

Comment: I don't know GetIt, but you could try to copy the source code of the 10.4 version to the 11 folder.

Comment: the amount of manual corrections increases from version to version. it's getting insane!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's really a mistake and I am not the only one.

https://quality.embarcadero.com/browse/RSP-35084